# iframe for Android apps using Phonegap not working

Tags: android, iframe, cordova

I have an problem with `iframe`. It's working fine in all browsers included android devices a. when it converting into android app using phonegap it's not working. Also it's appearing whole screen. Anyone please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add This code inside of `savedInstanceState` function

```
    super.appView.setWebViewClient(new CordovaWebViewClient(this, super.appView) {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
```

also add this code below import

```
import android.webkit.WebView;
```

Now it's working...:(:(:(