# Possible to load a web page in Ionic or Cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have a website that has a mobile view. I'd like to create an android apk that simply just loads the website when you open the app.

Is this possible (and relatively easy) utilizing Ionic or Cordova?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's simple and straight forward. You can just put the link to your website inside an `iframe` and you're done. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799682/show-a-website-inside-an-ionic-tab) for more info.

Answer (score 4):

Or, you can use inappbrowser. It's a browser inside of your app. You can even customize it not to display adress bars etc

http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

This is a nice example of usage

https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/07/launch-external-urls-ionicframework/

Comment: Awesome. I'll check this out too.