# How to show a website inside an ionic application without iFrame?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, iframe, ionic4

I looked around for quite a while but couldn't find anything that worked.

I am refering to this issue: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799682/show-a-website-inside-an-ionic-tab) - embeding a website inside your ionic application. Unfortunately the suggested solution using iframe works not for all pages since many websites have blocked iframe as you can see in the picture below.

I already tried the [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser) Plugin which works well. But it opens a full screen and hides my app navigation. You have to close the screen to get back to the application. Thats not really what I want. My InAppBrowserOptions are:

```
options : InAppBrowserOptions = {
    location : 'yes',
    hidden : 'no', 
    clearcache : 'yes',
    clearsessioncache : 'yes',
    zoom : 'yes',
    hardwareback : 'yes',
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction : 'no',
    shouldPauseOnSuspend : 'no', 
    closebuttoncaption : 'Close', 
    disallowoverscroll : 'no', 
    toolbar : 'yes', 
    enableViewportScale : 'no', 
    allowInlineMediaPlayback : 'no',
    presentationstyle : 'pagesheet',
    fullscreen : 'yes',
    hideurlbar : 'yes',
    hidenavigationbuttons : 'yes',
};
```

Is there a better way to embed the website inside the application?

[image]

Comment: Maybe this can help https://github.com/nioperas06/ultimate-cordova-webview-app

Comment: Hey,thank you for the Link! Problem is I already implemented an application with several functions. Now I want to display webcontent in one or two pages additionally. So a whole application just containing the web view isn't what I'm looking for.

Comment: Did you get any solution yet? I have been looking for the same thing from very long.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a few years late but as I see that there is still no solution, maybe I can help someone.

You need to use the target `_self` in create.

```
    const options: InAppBrowserOptions = {
        location: 'no',
        toolbartranslucent: 'no',
        toolbarcolor: '#00fff'
      };
      
    
    const browser = this.inAppBrowser.create(url, '_self', options);
```

if you look at the [documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)

> target: The target in which to load the URL, an optional parameter that defaults to _self. (String)
> _self: Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.

you need to add the urls in white list.

In `config.xml` add this inside the platforms, to accept all urls

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I think `InAppBrowser` is best. You can customize its settings to display the navbar. I insist you to use `InAppBrowser`.

Now coming to the `iframe` alternative you can use `embed` and `object`. But that also won't work in some cases.

To customize `InAppBrowser` visit this [link.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/customer-header-inappbrowser) You can also finds tons of tutorials regarding that.

I hope this helps! Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate how to change the settings to display the navbar? I added my InAppBrowserOptions. For further clarification - i would like to be able to access my application menu while the website is open.